# NextJS API Route, POST Request does not work with Firebase Hosting

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS Project. I am using NextJS 13 but with Pages Router.

The structure is this:

`src/pages/api/apiTest.ts`

This is the code in `apiTest.ts`:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { Logger } from "@utils/logger";

type ResponseData = {
  message: string;
};

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).send({ message: "Only POST requests allowed" });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello from Next.js!" });
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

Now after deploying it to Firebase Hosting using:

```bash
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I test it out with Postman.

When I do a GET Request:

[Results with GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99QNN.png)

But when I do a POST Request:

[Result with POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHKM1.png)

Does anyone know what the issue could be? I have been stuck with this issue for the past 2 days and cannot figure out what's wrong.

I have seen that using

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

should fix it because of the automated parser from firebase functions. But this doesn't work either.

**UPDATE**

When I send the POST request without a body, the API works. Why does NextJS API give error with sending a body when using Firebase Hosting?

I NEED to send body with the actually APIs that I have to build.

Comment: UPDATE:

I had opened an issue on Github and according to aalej there, its a version issue, and things work fine with 13.4.12.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6308#issuecomment-1705268896

The good part, I don't even need to use the `config` that I have exported in the above codebase now with v13.4.12